# Would adding more digits be a way to scale a order generation service?

Tags: design, algorithms, scalability, random, service

I am working on interview questions from [Amazon.com Software Development Engineer Intern Interview Questions](http://www.glassdoor.com/Interview/Amazon-com-Software-Development-Engineer-Intern-Interview-Questions-EI_IE6036.0,10_KO11,47.htm).

One of the interviewees was asked "give a scalable system design of Amazon.com's order number generation service."

I did some preliminary research [Amazon Order Number](http://www.quora.com/How-do-I-generate-unique-non-serial-order-numbers-similar-to-Amazon) and found that Amazon generates a 17 digit order number of the form 3-7-7, where the last 14 digits are seemingly pseudo-random with psuedo random meaning generated by an "algorithm that uses mathematical formulas to produce sequences of random numbers" [Psuedo-Random Definition](http://www.techopedia.com/definition/25842/pseudo-random-number-generator-prng)

I verified one on my own and saw that one of my order numbers - 112-9036246-9502632 followed this guideline.

How would you give a scalable, as in "ability of a computer application to continue to function as its size is changed to meet user end" [Scability](http://searchdatacenter.techtarget.com/definition/scalability) system design of this? To me this order number generation service is already pretty scalable cause that 3-7-7 combination should allow for a great range of combinations to accomodate for a great number of users. But if you wanted this service to be more scalable, would you just add more digits to the end to allow for more combinations of order numbers, that way you can accommodate for more orders?

Comment: Scalability is not only about the total size, but primarily about the throughput. How do you guarantee order numbers are unique when they are generated on multiple servers, in multiple threads, in parallel? Do you prevent collisions from the start? Doesn't that decrease randomness or leak other information? How do you seed the random number generators? Do you rely on DB transactions to guarantee uniqueness? But doesn't that slow everything down since it's a single global lock?

Comment: @amon Have a universal Amazon database and have a single lock on that database, so one server can insert a order number, and that lock would prevent other servers from checking until insertion is complete.

Comment: "a single lock on that database" is probably the definition of "not scalable" for this exercice.

Comment: But wouldn't that be the only way though to make sure that one server can complete its transaction before hand?

Comment: @gnat I agree but where else could i ask this? I talked to some people in chat and they said that as long as i ask a specific question, now "how do i start this" but something like "would this work", that be acceptable.

Comment: per my reading, in current form this is hardly a specific question, because it's _poisoned_ with stuff like "How would you go about this?" and "Are there other factors you have to take into consideration?" If you really have something specific in mind (the rest of the question suggests that this might be the case), consider [edit]ing it into a better shape

Comment: @gnat you're right, i should have gotten rid of those phrases to make the question more specific. Is it better now?

Comment: @AProgrammer I fixed the question

Comment: Can you guys unhold this? I fixed the question to make it more specific and i think this question would benefit any software engineer.

Comment: as of now, it has 2 votes reopen ([reopen review here](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/93995)). You may also check in chat where I [asked if it needs further improvements](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/20172513#20172513)

Comment: @gnat woah how did you link your message in chat?

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/faq#permalink

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is in the first three digits.  The last 14 digits are guaranteed to be unique within a certain domain, (say, a server,) so the first 3 digits must uniquely identify each domain.  Therefore, every 17-digit number is guaranteed to be unique.

Comment: But could you scale the order number generation service by adding more digits? Is domain just amazon.com?

Comment: Yes, of course you scale the order number generation service by adding more digits, but that's not the point. Domain in this case is not amazon.com, domain is one of amazon's order-taking servers.  So, for an order number to be unique, it needs to consist of a unique order-taking server number and a number that the server promises to be unique on the server.  So, it scales as you add more servers.

Comment: So they're both ways of scaling the order number generation service? What are the pros/cons of doing it the adding servers way vs adding more digits way?

Comment: The "adding servers" method implies adding digits in the sense that when you have 999 servers and want to add one more to have 1000 of them, a digit will automatically be added.  (Obviously.)

Comment: Simply adding digits to make the 14-digit random numbers even longer means increasing the storage capacity of each server by a factor of 10, which I am not sure is an option.

Comment: But wouldn't increasing the storage capacity meet the definition of scalability  in that the server is scaled up to handle more orders?

Comment: No, increasing the capacity of the machines is precisely what is ***not*** considered scalable.  Machines tend to be pretty fixed, or in any case there is a cap on how much you can beef them up.  Scalability is usually about expanding an algorithm over *more* machines, not about somehow squeezing more out of existing machines.

Comment: Cost wise, wouldn't you want to beef up one machine as much as you can? To me, it be much more expensive to buy more machines

Comment: All I am saying is that there is a cap to how much you can beef up each machine. Once you reach that cap, you will ***have to*** add more machines. Consequently, when we speak of scalability we hardly ever mean extensible hardware; we usually mean software which can be distributed over many machines.

Comment: If it's possible, would you prefer to add to the same machine(until you reach the cap) to avoid costs of buying new ones?

Comment: Yes, of course, I would max the machines before adding new ones.